# XAMPP phpMyAdmin - Error when exporting database (windows)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I was trying to export my database from `phpmyadmin` but it said in the browser couldn't upload a file when I tried again and it loaded to an HTML file.

```
index.php: Missing parameter: what \
index.php: Missing parameter: export_type
```

Comment: This seems to be happening because of some unnecessary extensions in your Chrome browser. Try disabling your extensions and then restarting your browser, this should fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded my xamp to version 7.4.29 and it worked